# WordPress when using the wp_update_post function to update the custom post type contents Gutenberg display the Classic block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have create a custom post type, that I'd like to update the post content using a custom Rest API Endpoint.

The way I update the content of the post is by using the function `wp_update_post`.

So far all work perfect. My actual issue is that when I open the post from the dashboard, the Gutenberg editor display the post contents using the block `Classic` like the following screenshot.

So I was wondering if there is any WordPress function that can convert the plain HTML I have from my front end client to Gutenberg blocks.

I've search a lot, but I cannot find anything. Maybe I have missed something.

For sure, it's not the end of the Word if I don't find a way to convert the plain HTML to Gutenberg blocks, but if I can have this option it will be nice :)

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Editor, click inside the *Classic* block to show the context menu then select *"Convert to blocks"*. This action transforms compatible classic content into blocks and works well for simple content like your example into paragraph blocks.
[image: Post > Classic]

The function that handles the conversion from raw HTML to blocks is [serialize](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/3da717b8d0ac7d7821fc6d0475695ccf3ae2829f/packages/blocks/src/api/serializer.js), a JavaScript function from the blocks API.  I've not found an equivalent core WordPress PHP function (as of 6.0) to convert classic content to blocks, so I wrote a simple one for plain text to be formatted as paragraph blocks, eg:

**php**

```php
/**
* Convert text to paragraph block markup that parse_blocks() will render
* @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/
*/
function convert_to_paragraph_block($text){
    $content = '';
    $paragraphs = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $text); // split text on newline

    foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph){
        $content .= sprintf('<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>%s</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->', $paragraph);
    }
    
    return $content;
}
```

If you use the above function to format the incoming content from your REST endpoint, the markup saved in `the_content` would be:

```html
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Duis aute ...</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I knew about the convert block button in the editor and already used that but I was looking more for native automated solution. Thank you also for your effort to write the PHP code ☺. I rather wait then for the core function conversion as my client side editor uses little more complicated HTML Than just paragraphs _(I have headings, paragraphs, etc)_. Again thank you ! :)